# Sms service in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

does iphone 4.0 support sms service??

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class (make sure to add the MessageUI framework to your project too).